# take array values of input boxes in controller using code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I  have form  in which five fields are displaying in one row.. two of them are select boxes and the remaining are simple input boxes .. I put this row in a for loop which is less than five so now my  form  has five rows each contain two dropdown and three textboxes .. I want to take their values into the controller.. how am i gonna do that ..? as I am new in code igniter so don't know how to I take their parameters in a controller as an array ... here is my code ..the code is not working..it is storing 0 for price and quantity and in a database

```
           <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id[]', $records2, 
         '#',   "id='category_".$i."' onchange='getItems(this.value,".$i.")' ");?>
        </td>

         <!-- Items --> 
           <td>&nbsp; <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id[]',
       $records3, '#',  "id='items_".$i."'"); ?></td>
                        <!-- end of Items -->


  <td><input type="text" name = "price_<?php echo $i ?>"
              id = "price_"<?php echo $i ?>>

     <td><input type="text" name = "quantity_<?php echo $i ?>"
              id = "quantity_"<?php echo $i ?>>

     <td><input type="text" name = "total_<?php echo $i ?>"
              id = "total_"<?php echo $i ?>>
                    </td>
            </tr>
   <?php }?>
```

I am doing this in Controller

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {


    $data3 = array(


            'item_id' => $this->input->post('item_id'),
                            'price' => $this->input->post('price_'.$i),
                'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity_'$i),
            // etc



    ); 
    }
            $this->load->model('salesModel');
    $this->salesModel->addSoldItemtoDB($data3);
```

Comment: update db on each pass of `for` loop, otherwise you are only updating last item

Comment: @charlietfl how am i gonaa do that ... do i put these two lines                    $this->load->model('salesModel');
    $this->salesModel->addSoldItemtoDB($data3);        into for loop

Comment: should be able to load model, then loop data

Comment: i didnt get you ..can you edit my question so i can understand clearly

Comment: load model, then run `for` and update db within `for`...not complicated

Comment: @ charlietfl thank youuuu ..you are genious.. only one problem is left .. how am i gonaa get the select box ids .. because above you can see that their names are like that item_id[]....

Comment: why are you using one format for naming input and another for select?  Please format code with proper intent next time, is very hard to read. Use same naming increment for select as for other fields

Comment: @charliefl becuse if i attach 'i' with them  then my dropdowns dont work .. because what my two dropdown is doing is that 2nd dropdown options comes against the selection of first dropdown box and if i increment them then selection dont work

Comment: don't understand that problem, easy to write script that will change them based on class and `TR` placement

Comment: thanks thanks ... i know what i was doing wrong ..thanks for your problem .. you dont know i was stuck here for two days .. you give me some  relief .. because this is the part ov my final year project